# Python logging, Loading config from ini file, KeyError with Formatters

Tags: python, logging, format, ini, python-logging

I'm trying to load the contents of `logging.ini` as the config file for the logger.
Having checked the docs and other posts with similar issues. I'm still unable to figure out what is causing this error.

i call it in my main view (Project is using MVC/layerd Architecture).

`logging.ini`

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
level=DEBUG
keys=file, console

[formatters]
keys=simple, verbose

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=file, console

[handler_file]
class=logging.FileHandler
formatter=verbose
level=WARNING
args=(src/data/files/output.log,)

[handler_console]
class=logging.StreamHandler
formatter=simple
level=DEBUG
args=(sys.stdout,)

[formatter_simple]
format=%(asctime)s | [%(levelname)s:%(name)s] | %(message)s

[formatter_verbose]
format=%(asctime)s | [%(levelname)s:%(name)s] | [%(module)s:%(funcName)s:%(lineno)s] | %(message)s
```

`console.py` (Main View)

```
import logging
from src.components.Utilities.loggingUtilities import LoggingUtilities
import pysnooper
# Other imports

class Console:
    def __init__(self, #controllers here):
        self.loagger = LoggingUtilities()
        # other variables

    def program_setup(self):
        self.logger.create_log_entry(level=logging.CRITCAL, message='starting setup')
        #  block of setup self methods
        self.logger.create_log_entry(level=logging.CRITICAL, message='Ending Program Setup')

     @pysnooper.snoop()
    def run(self):
        # Start Logger
        self.logger.start_logger()
        # Setup Program
        self.program_setup()
        # block of GUI code
```

`loggingUtilities.py`

```
import logging
from pathlib import Path

import pysnooper
from logging.config import fileConfig
from configparser import ConfigParser
from os import path

@pysnooper.snoop()
class LoggingUtilities:

    def __init__(self):
        self.parser = ConfigParser()
        self.main_logger = None
        self.settings_logger = None


    def setup_logger(self, config_path):
        logging.config.fileConfig(fname=config_path)
        self.main_logger = logging.getLogger('root')

    def create_log_entry(self, level, message):
        self.main_logger.log(level=level, msg=message)

    def start_logger(self):
        config_path = Path('src').resolve().parent.parent\
            .joinpath('data/files/logging.ini')\
            .as_posix()
        self.setup_logger(config_path)
        self.create_log_entry(level=logging.CRITICAL, message='Starting logger')
```

`Stack Trace`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~\ASP-T\src\app\ASP-T.py", line 37, in <module>
    main()
  File "~\ASP-T\src\app\ASP-T.py", line 33, in main
    run_program()
  File "~\ASP-T\src\app\ASP-T.py", line 29, in run_program
    console.run()
  File "~\ASP-T\venv\Lib\site-packages\pysnooper\tracer.py", line 305, in simple_wrapper
    return function(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "~\ASP-T\src\components\Views\console.py", line 133, in run
    self.logger.start_logger()
  File "~\ASP-T\venv\Lib\site-packages\pysnooper\tracer.py", line 305, in simple_wrapper
    return function(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File ~\ASP-T\src\components\Utilities\loggingUtilities.py", line 29, in start_logger
    self.setup_logger(config_path)
  File "~\venv\Lib\site-packages\pysnooper\tracer.py", line 305, in simple_wrapper
    return function(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "~\src\components\Utilities\loggingUtilities.py", line 19, in setup_logger
    logging.config.fileConfig(fname=config_path)
  File "~\Python\Python311\Lib\logging\config.py", line 71, in fileConfig
    formatters = _create_formatters(cp)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "~\Python\Python311\Lib\logging\config.py", line 104, in _create_formatters
    flist = cp["formatters"]["keys"]
            ~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "~\Python\Python311\Lib\configparser.py", line 978, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'formatters'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I tried changing the format and variables inside logging.ini, i've tried to use the relative rather than absolute path, i think it must be from the .ini structure though it seems to correct compared to the docs. Also tried altering the headers inside logging.ini, nothing chanaged.

Comment: Have you checked, e. g. with a `print`, that `config_path` contains the right path to the INI-file?

Comment: @MichaelButscher yes i have but pysnooper shows that correct path is assigned to config_path